# When the AppBarLayout's height go over than the screen,the TabLayout would be missed

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collaps_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="#451145" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="24545aga" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

if AppBarLayout set height="wrap_content",I can see TabLayout.Like this:

android:layout_height="wrap_content"
[image]

but when I set it "match_parent",TabLayout gone

android:layout_height="match_parent"
[image]

Anybody got this problem?I want put some actions in CollapsingToolbarLayout,but it can't more than one screen.

Comment: Hey, I got the same problem. Did you find any solution?